# Could you please tell me How to Retrieve image from Oracle Database to my android Activity

Tags: android, oracle, servlets

In My Android Application , I need to retrieve the image from oracle DataBase, and i worte servlet code so i need to send this image object from servlet to android activity, could you please tell me to that how can i send image object from servlet to my android activity..

Comment: Is it in a server folder or something like BLOB in Oracle database?

Comment: post your code / problem statements

Answer (score 1):

- Write A servlet which does Connect to DB, retrieve BLOB , read BLOB to inputstream and writes to OutputStrem as response.
- map above servlet to for eg '\image' which takes image name as param and searcher oracle based on param
- in Activity use url `host\image?<imagename>`